# Should a Flux action creator dispatch granular actions or sweeping ones?

Tags: javascript, flux

## The premise

I'm refactoring some Flux stores/actions/action creators to be more Fluxy (`PUBLISH`, `PUBLISH_SUCCESS`, `PUBLISH_FAILURE` instead of a weird `IS_LOADING` action), and was wondering how to structure my actions: should my action creators call single actions (`PUBLISH_SUCCESS`) or multiple ones (`ADD_AUTHOR`, `ADD_BOOK`, etc)?

## The example

Here's a more specific example:

I have a `TasksStore` that holds todo items for my innovative new task-management app, and I have a poorly named action creator `TaskActions` that lets me fetch my varieties from the server and add new ones with an API. Kinda like this:

```js
const TasksStore = { ... };

const TaskActions = {
    fetchTasks(),
    addTask()
};
```

What actions should I dispatch to communicate with TasksStore?

I see two options: action-creator-api-specific actions (`FETCH_TASKS`, `FETCH_TASKS_SUCCESS`, `FETCH_TASKS_FAILURE`, `ADD_TASK`, `ADD_TASK_SUCCESS`, & `ADD_TASK_FAILURE`) or reusable actions (`ADD_TASK` called over and over for fetch  and called once for `addTask()`).

Basically, should my API look like this (verbose, perhaps redundant, dispatch-able actions for each action-creator-action):

```js
const TasksStore = {
    on('FETCH_SUCCESS', (tasks) => { // add tasks });
    on('ADD_SUCCESS', (task) => { // add task });
};

const TaskActions = {
    fetchTasks() {
        dispatch('FETCH');
        myApi.fetchTasks(
            (success_payload) => { dispatch('FETCH_SUCCESS', success_payload) },
            (failure_payload) => { dispatch('FETCH_FAILURE', failure_payload) }
        );
    },
    addTask() {
        dispatch('ADD');
        myApi.addTask(
            (success_payload) => { dispatch('ADD_SUCCESS', success_payload) },
            (failure_payload) => { dispatch('ADD_FAILURE', failure_payload) }
        );
    }
};
```

or like this (concise, reusable dispatch-able actions):

```js
const TasksStore = {
    on('ADD', (task) => { // add task });
};

const TaskActions = {
    fetchTasks() {
        dispatch('FETCH');
        myApi.fetchTasks(
            (success_payload) => { 
                success_payload.forEach((task) => { dispatch('ADD', task); })
            },
            (failure_payload) => { dispatch('FETCH_FAILURE', failure_payload)
        );
    },
    addTask() {
        dispatch('ADD');
        myApi.addTask(
            (success_payload) => { dispatch('ADD', success_payload),
            (failure_payload) => { dispatch('ADD_FAILURE', failure_payload)
        );
    }
};
```

or something in between?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to go with the more verbose route:

For AJAX actions (like in the examples), we dispatch a specific "started" action, then a "success" or "failure" action:

```
dispatch('RETICULATE_SPLINES');
app.reticulateSpinesAndReturnPromise().then(
    (success) => { dispatch('RETICULATE_SPLINES_SUCCESS'); },
    (failure) => { dispatch('RETICULATE_SPLINES_FAILURE'); }
);
```

Why?

1. This decouples action creators from the actions a bit— action creators expose a uniform, grokkable API in the form of dispatched actions: `ActionCreator.fetchMessages` will dispatch a `FETCH_MESSAGES` action, not `ADD` or `FETCH_OR_ADD` or something weird. It's a lot easier to understand a decoupled system like actions and stores (decoupled because all actions travel through a dispatcher) when there are no unexpected dispatches.
2. It makes it a lot easier for multiple stores to listen for action-creator-actions. Does the `MessageThreadsStore` need to update when we `.fetchMessages()` but not `.postMessage()`? Listen for `FETCH_MESSAGES_SUCCESS`, not `ADD` which might have been called in both otherwise.

Anyway, hope that helps.